# CPLEX how to get all the different optimal solutions with the same cost

Tags: c++, optimization, cplex

I have a problem solved by Cplex that has at least two different optimal solutions with the same value.

How can I get all the different optimal solutions with the same value?

Update: it is a linear programming problem

Comment: Linear programming? Or nonlinear?

Comment: For MIP problems you can use the solution pool. For pure LP problems things are more difficult [[link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions-using.html)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could as said at

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d8d12e36-3150-4e1c-a956-d707d17f274c&ps=25

use the solution pool or an artificial objective in order to enumerate solutions.